# Pass data from listView to tabPage in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I am new to xamarin forms and I am trying to make a project similar to what you can see in the next picture.
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VqAA.jpg)

The thing I want to achieve is when I press an item from listView (which I already have with the items displayed) where I have all items I want to pass somehow the entire object to the tabPage so that I can see the description in one part and the opinions in the other page. I did some research but all the examples I saw uses MVVM and mine is more simple than that.
Here you have the code.

--->Model

```
public class Item
{
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public Double price;
    public int stock;
    public List<String> opinions;

    public Item(String name, String description ,Double price, int stock, List<String> opinions)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.opinions = opinions;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.name + " " + this.price + " $" + this.stock + " ud";
    }
}
```

---> The event that takes me to the TabPage.

```
 private async void parent_listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //here maybe I should pass the object...
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabPage());
    }
```

---> Here you have both classes that are used inside the tabPage

```
 public partial class Datos : ContentPage
{
    //private string descriptionList;
    public Datos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    
}


public partial class Opinions : ContentPage
{
    public Opinions()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   
}
```

The thing is that I don't know how to pass the object in a specific position from listView to both pages from tabPage in a easy way. I tried to pass both classes(Datos and Opinions) using TabPage constructor but it doesn't work. Here you have the code...

```
private async void parent_listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabPage(new Datos(itemList[e.SelectedItemIndex] ), new Opinions(itemList[e.SelectedItemIndex] )));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedItemChangedEventArgs` contains a reference to the selected object

```
private async void parent_listView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (Item)e.SelectedItem;

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabPage(item));
}
```

Comment: So in that case I have to make a specific constructor for TabPage and then automatically I will have the data inside Datos and Opinions classes? O I have to pass them the data somehow? Beg your pardon if it is a stupid question... but xamarin is not my field...by the moment

Comment: Pages are just C# classes.  If you want to pass data via the constructor, you will need to modify the constructor to accept those parameters.  Your TabPage will then need to pass the data to its children.

Comment: I get it till that point. But is there a way to pass the data to children without using mvvm. I mean by using a function or something like this. The examples I saw all uses viewmodel....

Comment: The child pages are just C# classes.  You can pass data to them using any C# technique - a public method, a public property, etc.  You can't use the constructor because the TabbedPage automatically creates the children using the default constructor.  OR, you can just set the BindingContext of the parent page, and the child pages will automatically inherit from their parent.